# Generalization of Comparable interface

Tags: java, comparable

Identity Interface was implemented in the system years ago. At this point, we got the necessity that each Identity should be Comparable. One of the options is to add additional **& Comparable** type to Identity declaration:

```
interface Identity<K> {

}

class Handler<T extends Identity<?> & Comparable<T>> {

  Handler(T value) {
    Util.<T>handle(value);
  }
}

class Handler2<T extends Identity<?> & Comparable<T>> {

  Handler2(T value) {
    Util.<T>handle(value);
  }
}

interface Util {

  static <T extends Comparable<T>> void handle(T value) {
  }
}
```

One of the main disadvantages is that a huge amount of code should be enhanced with identical information (e.g. **& Comparable**). 
Much elegant solution would be to extend Comparable interface with Identity one:

```
interface Identity<K> extends Comparable<Identity<K>>{

}
```

But in this case **Handler** class will highlight a compilation error:

> error: method handle in interface Util cannot be applied to given
>   types;  required: T#1  found: T#2  reason: explicit type argument T#2
>   does not conform to declared bound(s) Comparable where T#1,T#2
>   are type-variables:  T#1 extends Comparable declared in method
>   handle(T#1) T#2 extends Identity declared in class Handler

What are the possible solutions in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After changing `Identity` to what you suggested

```
interface Identity<K> extends Comparable<Identity<K>>{

}
```

You have two options. Either:

```
class Handler<T, U extends Identity<T>>
{
    Handler(U value) {
        Util.handle(value);
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
Handler<String, Identity<String>> stringHandler = new Handler<>(new FooIdentity());
```

or

```
class Handler<T>
{
    Handler(Identity<T> value)
    {
        Util.handle(value);
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
final Handler<String> stringHandler = new Handler<>(new FooIdentity());
```

And `Util` can remain unchanged.

Comment: in this case you have a Type recursion. As you would have **ConcreteType extends Identity<ConcreteType>** to be used for Handler.

Comment: @kvatashydze Right. Fixed it

Comment: yes this seems to be a solution, but the concern is that we are forced to use the Type inside of Handler, and not the **Identity** interface. So basically, all handlers should be written for concrete types.

Comment: @kvatashydze I don't understand. Can you give an example?